# numpy model.predict() doesn't function

Tags: python, numpy, keras

Hello i'm a newbie with Numpy, Keras and stackoverflow, i have a problem, i am in a loop

```
        roi = roi.reshape(28,28)
        roi = (np.linalg.norm(roi))
        probas = model.predict(roi)[0]
        #number = np.argmax(probas[i])
        #i+=1
```

And i am sure my reshape works
And it gives me

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-385-3ee67baef91d> in <module>()
----> 1 detect_digits("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/photo1.jpg", network)

3 frames

<ipython-input-384-79a58876db55> in detect_digits(image_name, model)
    49         # 2. Use 'model' to make a prediction
    50 
---> 51         probas = model.predict(roi)[0]
    52 
    53         # 3. Based on the prediction, determine the class (a number between 0 and 9)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
  1606           use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
  1607           model=self,
-> 1608           steps_per_execution=self._steps_per_execution)
  1609 
  1610       # Container that configures and calls `tf.keras.Callback`s.

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weight, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, initial_epoch, epochs, shuffle, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, model, steps_per_execution)
  1097       self._steps_per_execution_value = steps_per_execution.numpy().item()
  1098 
-> 1099     adapter_cls = select_data_adapter(x, y)
  1100     self._adapter = adapter_cls(
  1101         x,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in select_data_adapter(x, y)
   962         "Failed to find data adapter that can handle "
   963         "input: {}, {}".format(
--> 964             _type_name(x), _type_name(y)))
   965   elif len(adapter_cls) > 1:
   966     raise RuntimeError(

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.float32'>, <class 'NoneType'>
```

Can someone explain me i seriously don't understand what and where is the problem
Thanks for your answers

Comment: Hi. What is your model type ? If it is a Keras model, your input roi must be of type InputKeras

Comment: Hi, the model of "model" is

network = models.Sequential()
network.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(28 * 28,)))
network.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

Comment: Have you tried this (not sure but could be a solution) ? model.predict(np.array(roi))

Comment: I just tried it and my answer is :

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Show the traceback - i.e. the full error.  So far we are just guessing as to where the error occurs (apparently you are guessing as well).  Be more specific about the imports.  `model` is NOT a `numpy` creation.  It's something in the `keras` (I guess!).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem, the solution was :

```
roi = roi.reshape((1,28*28))
min = np.min(roi)
max = np.max(roi)
roi = (roi - min) * (1.0/(max - min))
probas = model.predict(roi)[0]
number = np.argmax(probas)
```

i was reshaping my matrix into a vector thats why my code wasn't working, thanks a lot for you're help !